# Why is this delete operation slower after a foreign key relationship has been added?

Tags: postgresql

Imagine the following table about cat owners.

```
drop table if exists  owners cascade;
create table owners(
    id bigint primary key generated always as identity ,
    name text not null
)
;

insert into owners(name)
select random()::text from generate_series(1,20000);
--insert 200,000 owners records
```

When I delete some of the owners records it is pretty fast:

```
delete  from owners
where id %10 = 0;
```

20000 rows affected in 85 ms

Now I add a table called 'cats' that refers to owners:

```
drop table if exists cats;
create table cats(
    id serial primary key ,
    name varchar(20000) not null,
    owner_id int not null references owners(id)
);

--insert 1bn cats records
insert into cats(name, owner_id)
select
       random()::text,
       owners.id
from generate_series(1,10), owners;
```

Lets delete some owners, but first we have to delete the cats that these owners 'own':

```
--delete the records in cats so we don't get a foreign key constraint violation
delete  from cats
where owner_id %10 = 1;


---now we do the same delete on owners as we did before
delete  from owners
where id %10 = 1;
```

2000 rows affected in 25 s 828 ms

Why is the second delete from owners ~5000 times slower than when we didn't have the cats table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the check if the owner is still referenced by the `cats` table during the DELETE. The check is essentially done using a `select * from cats where owner_id = ?` for every owner that you delete.

You can speed up the check by creating an index on the foreign key column:

```
create index on cats (owner_id);
```

Comment: It is common in my experience for people new to relational databases (and sometimes people who should know better by now!) to assume that indexes are automatically created to support all the checks needed to enforce each foreign key. Perhaps some DBs do this, or maybe some confusion comes from primary keys & unique constraints being implemented/enforced via indexes. But most DBs don't as it could be quite wasteful: application access patterns may mean it is not needed, or other indexes may support performant enough checks (in either case an automatic index would waste space, memory, & CPU).

Comment: The key issue here is that the target column owners.id is required to have an index by postgres, but the reverse is not true. That is to say, postgres effectively requires inserts into cats to be fast, but not deletes on owners.

Comment: @DavidSpillett: Foreign keys show up in `sysindexes` and it was taught that way when I was in college. I wonder if Oracle actually did it automatically.

Comment: @Joshua - are you sure? That seems wrong to me and certainly isn't the case elsewhere (for instance SQL Server). Could you have been working with a DB where the creator had added indexes supporting FKs that have the same name as those FKs? I'm pretty sure Oracle doesn't create indexes for FKs.

Comment: @DavidSpillett: There's a few reasons why sysindexes is obsolete. One of them is you had to decode an integer that was a bitflags to tell if it really was an index or a foreign-key record. Had all of us fooled at my company for a long time.

Comment: @Joshua: there is no `sysindexes` view in Postgres. And no, neither Postgres (which this question is about) nor Oracle automatically create indexes on foreign keys.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm talking about where the myth came from. Postgres is too young to be the source of the myth.

Comment: @ThatDataGuy: The *unique* index on the *referenced* column(s) is a logic necessity: the reference might be ambiguous otherwise. (A unique index is how Postgres enforces uniqueness! The performance benefit is a collateral benefit.) An index on the *referencing* column(s) is an optional performance optimization. Principal difference.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Nitpicking: it's more like a (cheaper) `EXISTS (SELECT FROM cats WHERE owner_id = ?)` for every owner to be removed.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: probably yes, that's why I wrote "essentially a ..."